How to programmatically get a Content Hub User's details by email
I have manually created a Content Hub user with Username as test@test.com. Also set this user's Email property to the same email.
Using Postman, I could fetch this user details with this query:

{{Hostname}}/api/entities/query?query=String('Email')=='test@test.com'

First I would get the token and then I would pass this token in another query to fetch the details.
When I try to do the same programmatically, the API response's Reason Phrase says "Not Found".
I am very sure the API endpoint URLs are correct, because I compared them in debugging.
ContentHubApiCredentials chac = new ContentHubApiCredentials
{
   user_name = Settings.GetSetting("ContentHub_Username"),
   password = Settings.GetSetting("ContentHub_Password")
};
string requestJson = chac != null ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chac) : string.Empty;
ApiServiceManager asm = new ApiServiceManager();
response = asm.GetPostAsyncResponse(Settings.GetSetting("ContentHub_GetTokenApiUrl"), null, requestJson);
json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.ResponseMessage);
string token = System.Convert.ToString(json.token); //I successfully get the token here

requestHeaderKeyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
requestHeaderKeyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("X-Auth-Token", token));
response = asm.GetPostAsyncResponse(string.Format(Settings.GetSetting("ContentHub_GetUserByEmailApiUrl"), email), requestHeaderKeyValues, string.Empty);


public ApiResponse GetPostAsyncResponse(string endPointUrl, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> requestHeaderKeyValues, string requestJson)
        {
            ApiResponse apiResponse = new ApiResponse();
            HttpResponseMessage res = null;

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                if (requestHeaderKeyValues != null && requestHeaderKeyValues.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in requestHeaderKeyValues)
                    {
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                    }
                }

                StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(requestJson, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                res = client.PostAsync(new Uri(endPointUrl), stringContent).Result;

                if (res != null)
                {
                    apiResponse.StatusCode = res.StatusCode.ToString();
                    apiResponse.ResponseMessage = res.Content != null ? res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result : string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    apiResponse = null;
                }
            }
            
            return apiResponse;
        }

In the GetPostAsyncResponse method, at the line res = client.PostAsync..., it returns Status Code as 404.

The call to fetch the user must be a GET Request. But since you are sending that as a POST request hence you are getting this issue.
You can change the code to below while searching for user through Query endpoint api.
res = client.GetAsync(endPointUrl).Result;

Moreover, would recommend you to use following endpoint for searching user through rest api, since email exist on both User and M.UserProfile entity definition.
/api/entities/query?query=Definition.Name=='User' AND String('Username')=='{Email}'

This specific search will search for email only on the User entity definition.
Note: The call to get the token must be a POST request but while searching for email through Email Api url, it must be a GET request.
Hope this helps!!!

I will try that. But here is an observation. I tried renaming the Username to "tester" and then adding the email as "test@test.com". In the query you have shared, it returns 0 results both with String('Username') and String('Email'). So in my case, a user can have the Username and/or Email as the email address and what is known for me is only the email.
